# linux slave is not coming online after jenkins service restart. Jenkins master is on windows

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I have Jenkins installed on Windows. I have two linux jenkins-agent nodes added to it.
for some reason I needed to restart the jenkins service and now my linux jenkins-agents are not coming online. When I go to these nodes I can see the option to mark them offline Which I believe comes when node is actually online like below

[image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kyR3.png]

How To bring these nodes back online. before jenkins restart everything was fine and I have not made any changes to agents.

**Changes I made to jenkins.xml before restart was **

1. Changed the java version
   <`executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.5\bin\java.exe</executable>`
2. Added keystore value in pre existing argument

   `<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx512m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="" -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8000 -httpsKeyStore="jenkins.jks" --httpsKeyStorePassword=xxxxx -webroot="%BASE%\war"</arguments>`

Comment: which connection method you are using to connect

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your changes had anything to do with the error. Try these options:

- Go into the Linux VMs and make sure they are online
- Ping the Linux VMs from the master VM to see if they are reachable
- Edit the slave node configuration, check everything is as it was before, and save
- Finally, remove the slave nodes and add them again